# DownloadManager not working for Android 10 (Q)

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I've been beating my head against this issue for quite awhile... I am updating an app that uses DownloadManger to do a simple task like downloading a file to the external storage public directory i.e:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

Everything works fine here from Android api 19-28. Its when testing on API 29 (Q/10) is where issues occur. Android implemented scoped storage and so deprecated the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory... As a result I need to figure out a compatible solution to support APIs 19-**29**. I cannot use internal application storage since DownloadManager will throw a SecurityException. Androids documentation states that I can use the DownloadManager.Request `setDestinationUri` and it even mentions for Android Q that I can use `Context.getExternalFilesDir(String)`. When I do this though, the path is still the emulated path:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package.name/files/Download/myFile.xml
```

I get a callback from the download manager that the download is complete (with right ID) but then I cannot grab the download from the area I saved it to. I check to see if the file exists and it returns false:

```
new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package.name/files/Download/myFile.xml").exists();
```

Any help is appreciated

Adding code for context. So setting up download manager

```
    private void startDownload() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);

        String remoteURL= getString(R.string.remote_url);

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(remoteUrl));
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
        request.setTitle(getString(R.string.download_title));
        request.setDescription(getString(R.string.download_description));
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "myFile.xml")));

        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        mainDownloadID= manager.enqueue(request);
    }
```

checking file if it exists:

```
new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "myFile.xml").exists(); //this returns false in the onReceive (and download IDs match)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add this into your manifest file in application tag

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: It's better change to the new methods instead of a quick hack that won't work in the next Android version

Comment: as @Andrew stated, I would like a more complete solution to the problem.

Comment: yes, its no so good, but it works, and if you need quick solution, its what you need

Comment: @Andrew check this https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html

Comment: @Сергей Серпивский yes I know all the info in this blog already, which is why I suggested moving to the new methods.

Comment: my scenario i  have already added android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=true , even i got same error android10 only

Answer (score 0):

File Paths outside of the App's private directories in Android Q and above useless.

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage

You need to ask the user where to download the files too, this will get you a URI for the `DownloadManager` destination.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory

You will probably want to persist this permission

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions

Comment: this is interesting, other apps do not need to access the file I am downloading. Question, how do I persist where the file location is that the user selected for the first time? I don't want to ask the user everytime, if I already downloaded it I just want to pull it from where the user first told me where to store it.

Comment: The last link shows you how to take permissions that survive a device restart. If other App's don't need to access the files you are downloading then it would be better to store them in your App's private directory instead which is much simpler as it does not require permissions

Comment: Right, but I would like to use the DownloadManager to download the files I need and it cannot take in the location of the apps private directory for the destination (will throw a SecurityException).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Its scope storage but even though you can download file in Q+ using downloadmanger no need to do `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

I am doing this way.

1. manifest

- -->

2. Downloadmanger

   ```
    val fileName =
        Constants.FILE_NAME + Date().time

    val downloadUri = Uri.parse(media.url)
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(
        downloadUri
    )
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
        DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE
    )
        .setAllowedOverRoaming(true).setTitle("Some name")
        .setDescription("Downloading file")
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, File.separator + FOLDER + File.separator + fileName
        )


    Toast.makeText(
        context,
        "Download successfully to ${downloadUri?.path}",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show()

    downloadManager.enqueue(request)
   ```

Hence it will ask write permission below Q, but in Q and Q+ it will download without asking permission in /Download/folder dir.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code and enjoy, this code uses RxJava for network call:

```
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.ObservableEmitter
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import java.io.*
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

    class FileDownloader(
         private val context: Context,
         private val url: String,
         private val fileName: String
         ) {
    
        private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
    
        private val errorMessage = "File couldn't be downloaded"
        private val bufferLengthBytes: Int = 1024 * 4
    
        fun download(): Observable<Int> {
            return Observable.create<Int> { emitter ->
    
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) { // To Download File for Android 10 and above
                    val content = ContentValues().apply {
                        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
                        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                    }
                    val uri = context.contentResolver.insert(
                        MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        content
                    )
                    uri?.apply {
                        val responseBody = getResponseBody(url)
                        if (responseBody != null
                        ) {
                            responseBody.byteStream().use { inputStream ->
                                context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { fileOutStream ->
                                    writeOutStream(
                                        inStream = inputStream,
                                        outStream = fileOutStream,
                                        contentLength = responseBody.contentLength(),
                                        emitter = emitter
                                    )
                                }
                                emitter.onComplete()
                            }
                        } else {
                            emitter.onError(Throwable(errorMessage))
                        }
                    }
                }
                    else { // For Android versions below than 10
                        val directory = File(
                            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absolutePath
                        ).apply {
                            if (!exists()) {
                                mkdir()
                            }
                        }
    
                    val file = File(directory, fileName)
                    val responseBody = getResponseBody(url)
    
                    if (responseBody != null) {
                        responseBody.byteStream().use { inputStream ->
                            file.outputStream().use { fileOutStream ->
                                writeOutStream(
                                    inStream = inputStream,
                                    outStream = fileOutStream,
                                    contentLength = responseBody.contentLength(),
                                    emitter = emitter
                                )
                            }
                            emitter.onComplete()
                        }
    
                    } else {
                        emitter.onError(Throwable(errorMessage))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        private fun getResponseBody(url: String): ResponseBody? {
            val response = okHttpClient.newCall(Request.Builder().url(url).build()).execute()
    
            return if (response.code >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK &&
                response.code < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MULT_CHOICE &&
                response.body != null
            )
                response.body
            else
                null
        }
    
        private fun writeOutStream(
            inStream: InputStream,
            outStream: OutputStream,
            contentLength: Long,
            emitter: ObservableEmitter<Int>) {
                var bytesCopied = 0
                val buffer = ByteArray(bufferLengthBytes)
                var bytes = inStream.read(buffer)
                while (bytes >= 0) {
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes)
                    bytesCopied += bytes
                    bytes = inStream.read(buffer)
    //                emitter.onNext(
                        ((bytesCopied * 100) / contentLength).toInt()
    //                )
                }
        outStream.flush()
        outStream.close()
    
        }
    }
```

On calling side you've to right this:

```
private fun downloadFileFromUrl(context: Context, url: String, fileName: String) {
    FileDownloader(
        context = context,
        url = url,
        fileName = fileName
    ).download()
        .throttleFirst(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            // onNext: Downloading in progress
        }, { error ->
            // onError: Download Error
            requireContext()?.apply {
                Toast.makeText(this, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }, {
            // onComplete: Download Complete
            requireContext()?.apply {
                Toast.makeText(this, "File downloaded to Downloads Folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
}
```