# downloading on DownloadManager and saving file in setDestinationInExternalFilesDir() is not working on Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0, download-manager

Im using `DownloadManager` to save the mp4 that comes from the server. Im saving the file on `storage/Emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files/.Videos`. I notice that on Android 9 and android 11 is successfully downloading it. But in Android 10 failed. I tried to enclose it on `try{}catch{}` method but i can't see anything on logs. I also try to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on my `Android Manifest.xml` but the error still occurs. I also refer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177136/downloadmanager-not-working-for-android-10-q) question which he/she using `setDestinationUri()` but still i can't find a way. BTW, this is my snippet of the `DownloadRequest`:

```
val path: String =
            context.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath + "/" + ".Videos"

val downloadmanager: DownloadManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        val request: DownloadManager.Request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setTitle(videoName)
            .setDescription("Downloading")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
            .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, ".Videos", "test1.mp4")
            //.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(File(path, "test.mp4")))
            //.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,videoName)
        val downloadId = downloadmanager.enqueue(request)
```

All response is deeply appreciated  :)

Comment: sorry about that, I updated it :).

Comment: At first glance i would say that your code should work.

Comment: it is working on android 9 and android 11. I'm confuse why is not working on android 10

Comment: Im thinking about the security on android 10 to save on external dirs. but i don't have enough information

Comment: No. For getExternalFilesDir() there is nothing special and you dont need to request read/write permissions or legacy external storage in manifest. Which device? Reboot your device.

Comment: I tested it on Emulator (Pixel 4 XL) and on Samsung Galaxy S10

Comment: Can you specify which android versions on which devices did you use?

Comment: Also, do you have the manifest permission?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev I use Huawei Nova 3 (Android 9), Samsung Galaxy S10 (Android 10) , Emulator Pixel 4 XL (Android 10), Emulator Pixel 3a (Android 11). Yes I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />`

Comment: I am not sure an emulator is a good call for such tests. Maybe a real device will also fail on 11. Do you have one at hand

Comment: @BorisStrandjev as of now, none. we can restrict the app to Android Q only since Android R is not been fully released yet

Comment: I disagree. I have a stock Pixel 3a, which is year and a half since released and is running 11 for some time now. Maybe you can try writing your own method to write in the same dir, just to see if you will face issue with that. Is '.Videos' existing already in all your devices? Maybe do a 'mkdirs' just to be sure.

Comment: You can set the DestinationInExternalFiles:- request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request). Give the permission of download.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this, it worked for my `pdf` download:

```
 request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, id+".pdf");
```

You can use this by changing the `Environment` variable, I think.

---

**Edit 1.0**

```
 try{
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadPath);

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);  // Tell on which network you want to download file.
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);  // This will show notification on top when downloading the file.
            request.setTitle("Downloading data..."); // Title for notification.
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
            request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer my bearertoken"));
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, id+".pdf");
            ((DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)).enqueue(request); // This will start downloading
        }catch(Exception e){
            
        }
```

Comment: what phone did you use?

Comment: I used this on `Emulator`, `Vivo`, `Realme`, and  `Samsung` smartphones. All were operating on `Android 10`.

Comment: oh okay, you're from ph :) . Can you paste your whole DownloadManagerRequest? thank you

Comment: this works like charm dude! *high five*. upon my observation, this code is missing `            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);  // Tell on which network you want to download file.` and i use also my path. thank you so much

Comment: have another problem on samsung devices, The notif is not showing but the download is running. how come

Comment: Which device and api?

Comment: Samsung S10, API 29

Comment: I don't have that device, you will have to find the solution for this.

Comment: how can save video using MediaStore for android 11?

Answer (score 0):

there is still issue in using  `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, "filename.pdf");`

this worked in my case:

```
    val file = File(getPicturesDirPath(this), filename)
    val destUri = Uri.fromFile()
    request.setDestinationUri(destUri)
    
    private fun getPicturesDirPath(activity: Context): String{
            val file: File = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)!!
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.parentFile.mkdirs()
                file.mkdir()
            }
    
            return file.absolutePath + "/"
    }
```

make sure you change Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES with your desired directory

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in android Q and after a few times, I found this is for its Persian file name. and when I change the name of file, it's fixed.